# odeint thrust slows down massively when using nested zip_iterators

Tags: thrust, odeint

I am building an analysis tool on top of odeint and thrust. The tool solves a large number of initial condition problems. I have had success following the odeint and thrust tutorials / demos. Up until now, the systems I have been working with have had less than 5 state variables, but now I need to extend the system to be capable of handling more.

As mentioned in the tutorial, there is a small problem that thrust's tuples can only have up to 10 items. This problem can be solved by using nested zip_iterators.

Quoting from near the bottom of [one of the tutorials](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/boost_numeric_odeint/tutorial/using_cuda__or_openmp__tbb_______via_thrust.html):

> "a small difficulty that Thrust's tuples have a maximal arity of 10. But this is only a small problem since we can create a zip iterator packed with zip iterators. So the top level zip iterator contains one zip iterator for the state, one normal iterator for the parameter, and one zip iterator for the derivative."

I have implemented this solution, and it works, but unfortunately with a massive loss in speed. For the same system (a two-variable system, simultaneously solving 8192 initial conditions), the original, simple but not-extensible to more than 5 variables solution runs in just over a second:

```
real   0m1.244s
user   0m0.798s
sys    0m0.356s
```

whereas the more complex, but extensible nested solution takes ~2000 times longer!

```
real    4m3.613s
user    2m15.124s
sys     1m47.363s
```

The only difference between the two programs is

1. inside the functor's `operator()`, where I refer to the state variables and derivatives, and
2. inside the functor's constructor, specifically the `for_each` command, where I create the zip_iterators and tuples.

Below I have included excerpts from these sections, for each program. I hope I am doing something wrong here, because this kind of speed loss is devastating! Any help would be much appreciated.

### Excerpts for "SIMPLE" code (non-nested-iterators)

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//// Inside ICFunctor's operator()
// getting the state variable
value_type X = thrust::get< 0 >( t );

// setting the derivative
thrust::get< 2 >( t ) = 0.5*A - 1.5*X;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//// the for_each statement that creates the zip_iterator
thrust::for_each(
    //// START INDICES
    thrust::make_zip_iterator( thrust::make_tuple(
        // State-variables
        boost::begin( x ) + 0*m_N,
        boost::begin( x ) + 1*m_N,
        // Derivatives
        boost::begin( dxdt ) + 0*m_N,
        boost::begin( dxdt ) + 1*m_N)) ,
    //// END INDICES
    thrust::make_zip_iterator( thrust::make_tuple(
        // State-variables
        boost::begin( x ) + 1*m_N,
        boost::begin( x ) + 2*m_N,
        // Derivatives
        boost::begin( dxdt ) + 1*m_N,
        boost::begin( dxdt ) + 2*m_N)) ,
ICFunctor() );
```

### Excerpts for "EXTENSIBLE" code (nested-iterators)

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//// Inside ICFunctor's operator()
// getting the state variable
const int STATE_VARIABLES = 0; // defined as a global constant 
value_type X = thrust::get<0>(thrust::get<STATE_VARIABLES>( t ));

// setting the derivative
const int DERIVATIVES = 1; // defined as a global constant 
thrust::get<0>(thrust::get<DERIVATIVES>( t )) = 0.5*A - 1.5*X;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//// the for_each statement that creates the zip_iterator
thrust::for_each(
    //// START INDICES
    thrust::make_zip_iterator( thrust::make_tuple(
        // State variables
        thrust::make_zip_iterator( thrust::make_tuple(
            boost::begin( x ) + 0*m_N,
            boost::begin( x ) + 1*m_N)),
        // Derivatives
        thrust::make_zip_iterator( thrust::make_tuple(
            boost::begin( dxdt ) + 0*m_N,
            boost::begin( dxdt ) + 1*m_N))
    )), 
    //// END INDICES
    thrust::make_zip_iterator( thrust::make_tuple(
        // State variables
        thrust::make_zip_iterator( thrust::make_tuple(
            boost::begin( x ) + 1*m_N,
            boost::begin( x ) + 2*m_N)),
        // Derivatives
        thrust::make_zip_iterator( thrust::make_tuple(
            boost::begin( dxdt ) + 1*m_N,
            boost::begin( dxdt ) + 2*m_N))
    )),
    ICFunctor() );
```

Comment: Using integrate_const instead of integrate_adaptive improved speeds substantially. (from 4 mins back down to 11 seconds). But what's going on here?

Comment: this seems very weird. maybe you can provide a minimal complete example so I can try to reproduce? perhaps you can also open an issue on odeints github page to discuss this: https://github.com/headmyshoulder/odeint-v2

Comment: You might also want to consider to use cuda's vector types like float4 or double4. Or you can even consider to implement your own array type based on double[N], where N is a small number and which is working on GPUs. This might allow you to avoid nested zip iterators.

Comment: While trying to put together the minimal example, I think I discovered that the source of the problem was different error tolerance levels between the programs. What is the proper ettiquette. Should I remove this question from Stack Overflow?